# Solr Query Single character

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I have a fieldType which is defined as below. Now, I have defined a field 'StatusCode' of this field type which holds a Single Character like A or P.  I have indexed the data using this fieldType and when I run a query like StatusCode:A it does not return any results.  Can someone please explain why the query is not working on Single character fields?

```
<fieldType name="text_exact_fuzzy" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
      <analyzer type="index">
          <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>           
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: 'a' is a typical stop word, so I would expect it not to be indexed, generally.  If searching for 'p' fails to get results, though, something else is going on.

Comment: It happens with all single characters which are not A also.  Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: what is the schema defination for the status_Code field. ? is it indexed true ?

Comment: yes, here is the schema definition for the status code <field name="statuscode"     type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems weird to define a field like StatusCode as text_exact_fuzzy and with those analyzers.

Use a simple StrField instead, without any analysis performed (only a lowercase filter factory if needed), and you should get the expected hits.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the statuscode to 'String' fieldType worked. I understand that the analyzers defined in the text_exact_fuzzy do not make sense for Single character fields.  But I still did not understand why using those analyzers would cause the query to fail in this case (If they are working with words with multiple characters then why not for single characters?).

Comment: They're designed to process the text in different ways, probably ending up with nothing at all. You might be able to check this by running your query in debug mode (use the admin interface).

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest you build up a query like this: (well lets call your field which contains your single characters TEST for this example)

Query = TEST:p AND TEST:a

Do you get any results?